# Remove value from a multivalue field?

Tags: xpages

I have a multivalue field on my document that I would like to remove a value based on the value.

I came up with this:

```
var doc:NotesDocument = rowData.getDocument();
var item:NotesItem = doc.getFirstItem("ValidProjects");
var a:Array = item.getValues()

for (var v in a)
dBar.info("Before removed V=" + v );

removeFromArray(a,compositeData.ProjectID);
doc.replaceItemValue("ValidProjects",a );

for (var v in a)
dBar.info("After removed V=" + v);


doc.save();


function removeFromArray(arr, val) {
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    dBar.info("Value = " + arr[i] + " Remove = " + val);
    if(arr[i] == val) {
        dBar.info("Removing " + i)
        arr.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
   }
}
```

The removeFromArray is being called successfully  and I can see the "Removing 0"  message displayed in the debugbar as expected but the array does not change at all and the value is not removed.   Any ideas?

Comment: item.getValues() returns a java.util.Vector and not an array. So maybe that's part of the problem. Also, I agree with John that I prefer that the function returns a value.

Comment: Array.splice wasn't correctly implemented in IBM Jscript (http://dontpanic82.blogspot.no/2010/10/code-snippet-arraysplice-according-to.html). At least the version used as SSJS. As Stephan Wissel have pointed out, you can use the Vector route, which is more predictable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat the ItemValues as Vector.

```
function removeFromItemValues(java.util.Vector vector, val) {
      // see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java
      vector.remove(val);
      return vector; //Optional
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick shot... I am not sure that arguments are passed "by reference"...?

If not, then that is the reason. I would normally prefer to use a function to return a value instead. From a programming point of view I find it more clear to read what the code does. In this particular example you would change your code to something like:

```
  function removeFromArray(arr, val) {
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        dBar.info("Value = " + arr[i] + " Remove = " + val);
        if(arr[i] == val) {
            dBar.info("Removing " + i)
            arr.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
       }
       return arr;
    }
```

and then you would call it like:

```
a = removeFromArray(a,compositeData.ProjectID);
```

You do not write whether you can see a change in your "After..." message? - or you just can see in the document that the value did not change?

Best regards

/John

Comment: Apparently, arrays are passed by reference: http://orizens.com/wp/topics/javascript-arrays-passing-by-reference-or-by-value/